# Python and pandas pivot table sum between dates

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

I have a pivot table which I have created using:

```
df = df[["Ref", # int64
        "REGION", # object
        "COUNTRY", # object
        "Value_1", # float
        "Value_2", # float
        "Value_3", # float
        "Type", # object 
        "Date", # float64 (may need to convert to date) 
        ]]


table = pd.pivot_table(df, index=["Region", "County"], 
               values=["Value_1", 
                       "Value_2", 
                       "Value_3"],
               columns=["Type"], aggfunc=[np.mean, np.sum, np.count_nonzero], 
               fill_value=0)
```

What I would like to do is add three columns to show mean, sum and nonzero of Value_1, Value_2 and Value_3 between these date ranges - <=1999, 2000-2005 and >=2006.

Is there a good way to do this using a pandas pivot table, or should I be using another method?

Df:

[image]

```
Ref REGION  COUNTRY Type    Value_2 Value_3 Value_1 Year
0   2   Yorkshire & The Humber  England Private 25.0    NaN 25.0    1987
1   7   Yorkshire & The Humber  England Voluntary/Charity   30.0    NaN 30.0    1990
2   9   Yorkshire & The Humber  England Private 17.0    2.0 21.0    1991
3   10  Yorkshire & The Humber  England Private 18.0    5.0 28.0    1992
4   14  Yorkshire & The Humber  England Private 32.0    0.0 32.0    1990
5   17  Yorkshire & The Humber  England Private 22.0    5.0 32.0    1987
6   18  Yorkshire & The Humber  England Private 19.0    3.0 25.0    1987
7   19  Yorkshire & The Humber  England Private 35.0    3.0 41.0    1990
8   23  Yorkshire & The Humber  England Voluntary/Charity   25.0    NaN 25.0    1987
9   24  Yorkshire & The Humber  England Private 31.0    2.0 35.0    1988
10  25  Yorkshire & The Humber  England Voluntary/Charity   32.0    NaN 32.0    1987
11  29  Yorkshire & The Humber  England Private 21.0    2.0 25.0    1987
12  30  Yorkshire & The Humber  England Voluntary/Charity   17.0    1.0 19.0    1987
13  31  Yorkshire & The Humber  England Private 27.0    3.0 33.0    2000
14  49  Yorkshire & The Humber  England Private 12.0    3.0 18.0    1992
15  51  Yorkshire & The Humber  England Private 19.0    4.0 27.0    1989
16  52  Yorkshire & The Humber  England Private 11.0    NaN 11.0    1988
17  57  Yorkshire & The Humber  England Private 28.0    2.0 32.0    1988
18  61  Yorkshire & The Humber  England Private 20.0    5.0 30.0    1987
19  62  Yorkshire & The Humber  England Private 36.0    2.0 40.0    1987
20  65  Yorkshire & The Humber  England Voluntary/Charity   16.0    NaN 16.0    1988
```

Comment: How does your df look like?

Comment: Thanks @MohitMotwani, I just added how I created the df to the question

Comment: But what's your data? Just show a dummy dataframe

Comment: Oh, sorry. I've just added a snip of it - is that enough? Value_3 is not all NaN, just for this sample it is.

Comment: @Maverick - Is possible create text version of data?

Comment: I just added 20 rows of the data to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) with column `Year` and then aggregate by [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
lab = ['<=1999','2000-2005',' >=2006']
s = pd.cut(df['Year'], bins=[-np.inf, 1999, 2005, np.inf], labels=lab)
#if exist only date column
#s = pd.cut(df['Date'].dt.year, bins=[-np.inf, 1999, 2005, np.inf], labels=lab)

f = lambda x: np.count_nonzero(x)
table = (df.groupby(["REGION", "COUNTRY", s])
          .agg({'Value_1':'mean', 'Value_2':'sum', 'Value_3':f})
           .reset_index())
print (table)
                   REGION  COUNTRY       Year  Value_1  Value_2  Value_3
0  Yorkshire & The Humber  England     <=1999     27.2    466.0     19.0
1  Yorkshire & The Humber  England  2000-2005     33.0     27.0      1.0
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but not sure it is doing what I want? I want to have the three columns ('<=1999','2000-2005',' >=2006') at the end, which summarises mean, sum and nonzero for Value_1, 2 and 3. Rather than an index?

Comment: @Maverick - Can you check now?